# How do I make Prism.js syntax highlight a section of code AFTER another JS file sets the contents?

Tags: javascript, prismjs

I am currently trying to make a website where different codes are loaded in at different times. However the content of these codes are stored in a JSON file and are loaded in to the page through JS.

Prism.js seems to run syntax highlighting at load time and I would like to run syntax highlighting on the code after it has been loaded from the JS.

Is there any way I can do this using Prism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to call one of [`highlightAll()`](https://prismjs.com/docs/Prism.html#.highlightAll), [`highlightAllUnder()`](https://prismjs.com/docs/Prism.html#.highlightAllUnder) or [`highlightElement()`](https://prismjs.com/docs/Prism.html#.highlightElement) after the content has been loaded to highlight them:

```js
setTimeout(
  () => {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
      'beforeend',
      '<pre><code class="language-css">.async-loaded { color: red }</code></pre>',
    );
    
    window.Prism.highlightAll();
  },
  1000
);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.29.0/themes/prism.min.css" integrity="sha512-tN7Ec6zAFaVSG3TpNAKtk4DOHNpSwKHxxrsiw4GHKESGPs5njn/0sMCUMl2svV4wo4BK/rCP7juYz+zx+l6oeQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.29.0/prism.min.js" integrity="sha512-7Z9J3l1+EYfeaPKcGXu3MS/7T+w19WtKQY/n+xzmw4hZhJ9tyYmcUS+4QqAlzhicE5LAfMQSF3iFTK9bQdTxXg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.29.0/plugins/autoloader/prism-autoloader.min.js" integrity="sha512-SkmBfuA2hqjzEVpmnMt/LINrjop3GKWqsuLSSB3e7iBmYK7JuWw4ldmmxwD9mdm2IRTTi0OxSAfEGvgEi0i2Kw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<pre><code class="language-css">.pre-loaded { color: green }</code></pre>
```